# Optimize jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I optimize this sample snippet:

Note that it has multiple calls to locate the #data and #click tags.

```
$(function(){
    $('#data').hide();
    $('#click').click(function() {
      $('#data').toggle('', function() {
      });
    $('#click').hide();
    });
})
```

Comment: What problems are you currently experiencing with this code that might require optimization? What kind of optimization do you require: code shortening or some performance?

Comment: I'm looking for a new approach

Comment: Seems quite succinct if you ask me

Comment: @MiniNaim, new approach to do what? You haven't even explained what you are trying to achieve. It's kinda difficult to propose a new approach without knowing what you are trying to approach.

Comment: It's clear and simple, I want to display a hidden content when I click on a button.

Comment: @Darin: It's pretty obvious that he just wants to optimize the snippet of code that was posted. There is no deeper meaning to this question, if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Sure, it might be obvious to anyone familiar with jQuery what he's trying to do; and that's only assuming he knows what he's doing.  However, without describing what he's trying to achieve, it's not very helpful to the newbies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two less lines of code.

```
<style type="text/css">
 #data{display:none;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){
    $('#click').click(function(){
       $('#data,#click').toggle();
    });
});
</script>

<div id="data">Some data</div>

<button id="click">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure.

```
$(function(){
    var data = $('#data');
    var click = $('#click');

    click.click(function() {
        data.toggle();
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Cache your selectors in variables if you plan to use them later. Don't use jQuery for something you can accomplish with CSS. So instead of hiding `data` with `data.hide()` do it in your CSS with `display:none`.

See this question: [jQuery Standards and Best Practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245598/jquery-standards-and-best-practice)

Comment: Could do `click.hide()` inside of the click callback?

Comment: Shouldn't `click.hide()` here be inside the `click` handler? Otherwise it hides the '#click' element as soon as `$(document).ready()` is evaluated. I assume the OP wants the '#click' element to be hidden only on click (otherwise, how can I click it?).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is no need to repeat $("#data") and $("#click") - assign them to variables and then reuse them. In you current code, it is having to locate the items twice.