# Jquery Bad practices

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, code-standards

What are the JQuery bad/worst practices you have seen, written or thing should be avoided?

Comment: I know I already commented, but this question is an exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229259/jquery-pitfalls-to-avoid

Answer (score 33):

A thing you should avoid is using the "easy to use" selectors in every line once again, because the JavaScript implementation of selectors is not *that* efficient. Of course, the jQUery guys are optimizing it, however I think you should use it as little as possible.

So, this is a bad practice.

```
$("li ul span").show();
$("li ul span").toggleClass("bubu");
```

Chaining is good

```
$("li ul span").show().toggleClass("bubu");
```

And remembering things in a local variable is also not bad:

```
var allspans = $("li ul span");
allspans.show();
allspans.toggleClass("bubu");
```

Comment: Yeah, so many people do this. It's so bad for performance.

Comment: +1 for pointing out chaining and local variables!

Answer (score 17):

There are two that I see alot:

**First**, in a click event, the `id` is accessed like this:

```
$("a").click(function(e){
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

That creates a *new* jQuery object around the DOM node, *and* calls a function. The following is the correct way:

```
$("a").click(function(e){
   var id = this.id;
});
```

*Note: That you will also see `$(this).attr('href')`, but that is correct because of the way jQuery normalizes it across browsers.*

The **second** is passing anything except a DOM node into the `scope` parameter of the jQuery call:

```
$(".child", $(".parent")).doSomething();
// or
$(".child", ".parent").doSomething();
```

There is no speed gain at all by doing this. Where you do see a speed increase, is when you already have the DOM element:

```
$('div').click(function(){
   $('img', this).doSomething(); // This is good
});
```

Answer (score 5):

James Padolsey has written [an excellent article](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-code-smells/) on jQuery code smells.  I recommend reading it.

Answer (score 2):

Still using the old document ready function:

```
$("document").ready(function(){ });
```

Instead of the very common:

```
$(function(){ });
```

It's not really bad, but I shows people not getting up with new api's.

Comment: Using `$(document).ready(...)` is often used to make the code explicitly clear. Of course it is not needed, but its hardly a bad practice IMO.

Comment: can you explain, why should I do that? I think, the first version makes more sense - we're attaching an event handler to the DOCUMENT object. The other one.. even tho it maybe works better.. does not explain itself.

Comment: In that case I reference too http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#callback  Like I said it's not bad practice, it's more a notice that people don't catch up on the latest api. They prefer to make readable code, instead of fast and minified code.