# Fetching external webpage to iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm rather a noob to JavaScript and jQuery, so I need some help. WIthin my app, I've implemented a DatePicker calendar, loaded through an external js, and it works perfectly fine. I want to implement a jQuery button which can catch the date, i.e: 3rd of August, and fetch me a wikipedia page www.wikipedia.org/August_3. I also want this page to be uploaded to an iframe below. How can I do that in jquery? Here are the simpliefied versions of the html and the js respectively.

```
<head>
    <script src=".../jquery.ui.button.js" type="text/javascript">
    <script src=".../jquery.ui.datepicker.js" type="text/javascript">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="/.../myscript.js" type="text/javascript">
    <div class="demo">
        <p>Date: <input id="datepicker" type="text"></p>
    </div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
          $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Please format your post correctly, add code tags, remove non esential non printable characters.

Comment: 1. Learn JS. 2. Try to implement it. 3. Ask specific questions when you have a specific problem.

Comment: This is more of a request than a question. You requesting someone to build all the functionality for you. Try this [peopleperhour.com](http://www.peopleperhour.com/). But seriously, you say you're new to jQuery, try doing this yourself and learn, it will benefit you in the future

Answer (score 7):

> I'm rather a noob to javascript and jquery, so I need some help.

**Starter**

[Mozilla JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide)

[jQuery DOCs](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page)

[jQuery tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials)

**Advanced**

[Mozilla JavaScript DOCs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript)

[ECMA 5 DOCs](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)

[Douglas Crockford JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/)

[JavaScript best practices](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.general)

[Quirks Mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/)

**Books**

[Recommended JavaScript books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74884/good-javascript-books)

**Tools**

[JS Lint](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) to check for bad written code

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to try out your scripts or piece of code

**AVOID!**

[jQuery pitfalls to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229259/jquery-pitfalls-to-avoid)

<del>w3schools</del> Check http://w3fools.com/

**Personal advice**

Remember jQuery is a library written in JavaScript, everything jQuery does can be done with plain JavaScript. Using a library such as jQuery is a good thing, because it will ensure cross-browser compatibility, has a large community, you need to write less code, and so on... but please don't abuse it. You can do simple tasks with JavaScript, avoiding useless function calls and slow scripts.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I do that in jquery?

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker()
        .bind(
            'dateSelected',
            function(e, selectedDate, $td)
            {
                Date.format = 'yyyymmdd';
                var dateStr = selectedDate.asString();
                $('#myIframe').attr('src', 'http://www.wikipedia.com/' + dateStr);
            }
    );
});
```

Read up on the [DatePicker docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker) and [this](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerKarmasAgent.html).

Comment: thanks mate,l that helped a lot