# Is $('selector', element) the same as element.find('selector')?

Tags: jquery

I was looking this post about best practices of jquery [jquery-pitfalls-to-avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229259/jquery-pitfalls-to-avoid) in one of the answers someone said about the good uses of context in a selector and quotes a examples like this

```
var ct = $('#container');
$('.myClass',ct)
```

With the finally to explain that this will find in the context of the `container` and not in all the document. Now my question if that code is not the same that this function

```
var ct = $('#container');
ct.find('.myClass')
```

Comment: I seriously want to edit your title because I don't understand it -- but I can't figure out what it should say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is exactly the same. In fact, the first version delegates to the second (making the second slightly faster).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can just use

```
var ct = $('#container .myClass');
```

Comment: In this example the context is a selector, but it can be other things too