# Using Javascript function variables to define a DOM element

Tags: javascript, forms, function, variables

I'm using a yes/no dropdownbox to hide conditional form elements via CSS. It works fine if I manually define the form name and element name, but if I try to define them via variables it won't function. I've been troubleshooting and researching for about an hour to no avail. Here is my Javascript function.

```
function binaryHideShow(formName, elementName)
{
    if (document.forms["'" + formName + "'"].elementName.value == "yes")
    {
        document.getElementById("'" + elementName + "'").setAttribute("class","show");
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("'" + elementName + "'").setAttribute("class","hide");
    }
}
```

And here is the HTML element.

```
<select name="PrimaryFiledBankruptcyDropDownList" onchange="binaryHideShow(this.form.name, this.attributes['name'].value);">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="yes">Yes</option>
<option value="no">No</option>
</select>

<div id="PrimaryFiledBankruptcyDropDownList">
<label for="PrimaryBankruptcyTypeDropDownList">Bankruptcy Type:</label> 
<select name="PrimaryBankruptcyTypeDropDownList" onchange="">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="chapter-7">Chapter 7</option>
<option value="chapter-13">Chapter 13</option>
</select>
</div>
```

I've already ensured that my this statements on the html side are pulling the correct elements.

To be clear if I manually enter the variables names as per the example below it will work fine, and the html this statements return the EXACT names that I'm using below.

```
function binaryHideShow()
{
    if (document.forms["ProgramApplicationForm"].PrimaryFiledBankruptcyDropDownList.value == "yes")
    {
        document.getElementById("PrimaryFiledBankruptcyDropDownList").setAttribute("class","show");
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("PrimaryFiledBankruptcyDropDownList").setAttribute("class","hide");
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems strange to me that you hide the same dropdown list in which you select yes/no, shouldn't you be hiding the **other** dropdown list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your function for access the element in your form, try:

```
function binaryHideShow(formName, elementName)
{
    if (document.forms[formName][elementName].value == "yes")
    {
        document.getElementById(elementName).setAttribute("class","show");
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(elementName).setAttribute("class","hide");
    }
}
```

Comment: When possible you'd better use object reference instead of names, see *anAgent*'s examples.

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
document.forms["'" + formName + "'"]
```

to

```
document.forms[ formName ]
```

Otherwise you're passing in a name as if you did "'PrimaryBankruptcyTypeDropDownList'" (note the double quotes).

Comment: I tried removing the quotes from the formName, elementName and a combination of either of the two and it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started.

**HTML**

```
<form name="MyForm" id="MyForm">
    <select name="PrimaryFiledBankruptcyDropDownList"nchange="binaryHideShow(this,this.form);">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="no">No</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function binaryHideShow(element,form) {
    console.log("Element Name: " + element.name);
    console.log("Form Name: " + form.name);
    if(element.value == "yes") {
        console.log('sure does');
    } else {
        console.log('nope');
    }
}
```

Off topic - but, you might find this useful...

Look into separating your actions from your view - meaning: get rid of the "onchange" event and if possible - think about using jQuery.

Some good reads for you:

- http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2008/09/16/jquery-examples-and-best-practices/
- https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rules_intro
- [jQuery pitfalls to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229259/jquery-pitfalls-to-avoid)
- http://www.tvidesign.co.uk/blog/improve-your-jquery-25-excellent-tips.aspx#tip2
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/14-helpful-jquery-tricks-notes-and-best-practices/

Comment: That work's but it doesn't serve the same purpose as the function I'm trying to create. I want to be able to hide or show a div with the same id as the event element's name by passing in the name of the form and element to the function. I have a lot of these binary conditionals and I'd rather not write a separate function for each one if I can just pass variables instead.

Comment: Also what is the valid way in which to pull the form name that an element is in instead of this.form.name?

Comment: You didn't include all of the html. So, if your elements are wrapped in a form tag, then "this.form.name" is valid.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out. In order to use the element portion of the document.forms you have to specify elements[] with the variables inside as such:

```
function binaryHideShow(formName, elementName)
{
    if (document.forms[formName].elements[elementName].value == "yes")
    {
        document.getElementById(elementName).setAttribute("class","show");
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(elementName).setAttribute("class","hide");
    }
}
```