# jquery submit form

Tags: jquery, html, validation, forms, jquery-plugins

I got stuck today, been searching on stack overflow and google, however havnt had much luck in implementing the solutions I've seen. I have a form, Im trying to create, when i click submit when theres no info in the forms, it prompts an error (it didnt validate), however when everything is filled out correctly, the submit button no longer works.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.delegate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
 debug: true,
 success: "valid"
});;
</script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#q0").validate({
  rules: {
   date1: {
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    rangelength: [4, 4],
    min: 2010,
    max: 2015
  },
   date2: {
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    rangelength: [2, 2],
    max: 12
  },
   date3: {
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    rangelength: [2, 2],
    max: 31
  },
   date4: {
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    rangelength: [2, 2],
    max: 23
  },
   date5: {
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    rangelength: [2, 2],
    max: 59
  }
 }
});
  });
  </script>
```

Next we have the form:

```
<h1>Select User</h1>
   <form action="q1.php" method="post" id="q0"><br /><br />

<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('PWND: ' . mysql_error());
  }

                mysql_select_db("questionnaire");


    $sql = "SELECT id, fname, lname 
      FROM   User";

                $result = mysql_query($sql);
     echo '<select name="User" type="number">';
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['fname'].' '.$row['lname'].'</option>';
                }
     echo '</select>';
mysql_close($con)
?><br /><br />
<p>
<h4>Date and Time</h4>

  <label for="date1">Year (YYYY): </label>
  <input class="left" id="date1" name="date1" />
  <br/>
  <label for="date2">Month (MM): </label>
  <input class="left" id="date2" name="date2" />
  <br/>
  <label for="date3">Day (DD): </label>
  <input class="left" id="date3" name="date3" />
  <br/>
  <label for="date4">Hour (HH): </label>
  <input class="left" id="date4" name="date4" />
  <br/>
  <label for="date5">Minute (MM): </label>
  <input class="left" id="date5" name="date5" />
  <br/>
</p>
<h4>Test</h4>
<select name="qtype" type="number">
<option value="1">0</option>
<option value="2">8</option>
<option value="3">1</option>
<option value="4">2</option>
<option value="5">3</option>
<option value="6">4</option>
<option value="7">5</option>
</select><br /></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Basically I would like it to post to the next page, like it did previously, however since I tried jquery the submit button has stopped working, seems like after it validates.

I've been looking at:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation (this was my main resource to getting this going).
[jQuery disable button (NOT Submit) until field validates + Validation Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882406/jquery-disable-button-not-submit-until-field-validates-validation-plugin)
[Help understanding jQuery button enable/disable code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075651/help-understanding-jquery-button-enable-disable-code)

However I still seem to be stuck, not sure I messed up the code above somewhere. The submit button remains broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the [`debug` option](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) you have set:

```
debug: true,
```

Just remove the option or set it to `false`, it prevents submission for testing, to get a submit to go through you'll need to change it, from [the docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions):

> Prevents the form from submitting and tries to help setting up the validation with warnings about missing methods and other debug messages.